# Swing JToolbarButton pressing

Tags: swing, jbutton, jtoolbar

I use JToolbarButton button, I want to make it be "pressed" when I click on it, just like JButton works.How can I do this?
Please help!Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "JToolbarButton" (there is no such beast in core Swing)

Comment: I mean pictograph(icon) button, small button, displayable often without label only small image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in Costis' reply, you are probably after a [`JToggleButton`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359906/swing-jtoolbarbutton-pressing/7360696#7360696).  It might also be necessary to suppress the painting of the border, as in the 2nd tool bar in this example.

[image: Toggle Bar]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ToggleBar {

    public static JToggleButton getButton(
        Image selected,
        Image unselected,
        boolean decorated) {

        JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton();
        b.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(selected));
        b.setIcon(new ImageIcon(unselected));
        b.setBorderPainted(decorated);

        return b;
    }

    public static Image getCircleImage(Color c) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
            32,32,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();

        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillOval(0,0,32,32);

        g.dispose();
        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Image red = getCircleImage(Color.RED);
                Image green = getCircleImage(Color.GREEN);

                JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));

                JToolBar tb1 = new JToolBar();
                for (int ii=0; ii<5; ii++) {
                    tb1.add( getButton(red, green, true) );
                }
                p.add(tb1);

                JToolBar tb2 = new JToolBar();
                for (int ii=0; ii<5; ii++) {
                    tb2.add( getButton(red, green, false) );
                }
                p.add(tb2);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a JToolbarButton in [Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/index.html).

It seems to me though that what you are looking for is a [JToggleButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html). You can adjust it to display a small image and to be small.

```
jToggleButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("image.png"));
jToggleButton1.setSelectedIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("selected_image.png"));
```

Add another image with setSelectedIcon in order to make you button look pressed.

Comment: I want that label also looked pressed.

Comment: Do you mean the text of the button?