# Best way to make a Java map maker?

Tags: java, swing, 2d, platform, jcomponent

I am making a 2d platformer and am producing the map maker. So far, I have my java project splitting an image of tiles into 100 seperate images, and putting them in buttons (tile[]). When one of these buttons is clicked, it fires the MouseListener:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
            tile[i].setBackground(null);
    }
    ((JComponent) e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.black);
}
```

Now, I need to know if there is a JComponent that can make this easy for me, I want to be able to click in a canvas or something, and start drawing the map (24x24 pixel grids). How would I go about doing this? If you need more code or me to explain better please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`JToggleButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) as shown in [Swing JToolbarButton pressing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7360696/418556).

[image]

Obviously this will require 2 images for each map 'tile' location.  The first is the map tile for that part of the map, the second is a black image that can be reused for every tile.

Comment: +1 You can tile a full image using `getSubimage()`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513).

Comment: I didnt use `getSubImage()` to cut, instead I used `CropImageFilter()`, does it matter? Or are they both efficient enough?

Comment: @trashgod Huh.. to be honest, that is the first time I've heard of [`CropImageFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/CropImageFilter.html).  My 'learn item' of the day.  Why don't you run some quick tests and report back?  BTW - I notified trashgod on this comment though most of it was directed to Qasim.  The reason being I doubt the former would have been notified, and they were the one clever enough to suggest `getSubImage()`. ;)

Comment: BTW - congrats on achieving a working example.  Whether efficient or otherwise.  :-)

Comment: @Andrew: I may have misinterpreted the question; I've not used `CropImageFilter` before.

Comment: @trashgod Ehh (shrugs) it seems like either could do the job, and unless it became a performance issue, I would not even bother to test which is more efficient.