# 2D Button Array ActionListener, color change?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jbutton, multidimensional-array

I have this 2D `JButton` array (color white), and what I want to do is when I click on a square, it'll turn into orange. When I click another square, that square becomes orange as well but the first square I clicked will return to its normal white color. How do I do it without having all the squares turn into orange?

Here's a visualization:
[image]

Btw, when I click the squares with the numbers, their colors do not change, think of them as like `setEnabled(false)` buttons. I already know how to change the colors of the buttons, I just want to know how the color gets passed on square after square.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Edit: My "attempt" but it's making all of my `null` valued buttons orange.

```
button[i][j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       for(int i = 0; i < button.length; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < button.length; j++){
               if(g.gameBoard[i][j] == null){
                   //must find the position where the user clicks and make it orange
                    button[i][j].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
               }
           }   
       }
});
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? And where exactly are you stuck? For my money, though, if the buttons don't have an intrinsic "action" other than turning colors, I'd use JLabels and a MouseListener, but would need to remember to set the JLabel's opaque property to true so that they would draw their background color.

Comment: you can pretty use Arrays of JToggleButtons, for better help sooner please edit your post with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've tried create in instance of JButton in my actionListener like so: `ae.getSource() instanceof JButton` but it's making all of my buttons turn orange when I click them.

Comment: *"if the buttons don't have an intrinsic "action" other than turning colors, I'd use JLabels and a MouseListener,"*  Horrified!  What about us poor saps who hate mice?  A button will react to keyboard (or mouse) input.  BTW - sorry about that qn. yesterday.  I hoped the OP would have the sense to pick your answer.  ..Suppose that was a bit optimistic of me.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7360696/418556) might be of relevance.

Comment: @Andrew: oh you mean the moving polygon question? p'shaw, not to worry. But *next time* I'll be sure to upload an even prettier picture, you can be sure on that!

Comment: @Hover You wanna' challenge the Van Gui of screenshots to a screenshoot-out?  Now *you're* the optimistic one! Are we about to see a Hovercraft Full Of Impressionists? ;)

Comment: @Andrew: more like Hovercraft-full-of-chit. We'll see, we'll see.

Comment: Please take your conversation somewhere else D: I got excited about my notifications thinking I had an answer only to think it's you guys, but all is forgiven :))

Comment: @taeyeon: point taken. Now perhaps you would like to address some of our comments that were directed to your original post?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've already responded to your comment :) I'll try making `JToggleButtons` as well.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that, sorry. You've got something wrong with your code logic which is why it didn't work. Consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) if you still are stuck on this step.

Comment: @taeyeon **Please take your conversation somewhere else D: I got excited about my notifications thinking I had an answer only to think it's you guys, but all is forgiven :))**, no we are still waiting for your code :-)

Comment: @mrKorbel The code I have used so far? Okay I'll post it up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [JToggleButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) and put them in a [ButtonGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html) so that you can treat them as a group and set the color to the activated one.

P.S. i will keep in contact with this thread for the next 24 hours if there is any question i will try to explain more.

Comment: Cool! It worked! Thanks a lot! I'm not planning on changing the color to orange anymore :)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(e.getSource()== null)
{
    //must find the position where the user clicks and make it orange
     button[i][j].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
}
```

Try This above code  in the public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method.