# JButton from image

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I want to make JButton from image. But when i do it like this:

```
private void AddMainActionsButtons(Container powZawartosci){
  JPanel mainActionButtons = new JPanel();
  JButton applyButton = createImageButton("obrazki/apply.png");
  mainActionButtons.add(applyButton);
  powZawartosci.add(mainActionButtons);
  mainActionButtons.setBounds(150,530,400,90);
}

private JButton createImageButton(String imagePath){
  ImageIcon icon = uploadImage(imagePath,"");
  JButton button = new JButton(icon);

  return button;
}
```

JButton looks bad, because image is inside button component, and in fact I got image on image. How can I create as big JButton as my image, and how to cover it by image in 100%. In other words: how to make my image be a Button?

Comment: Robin I wont say that this edition of my code is bad. Because it is not. But in my opinion method "createImageButton" should be one level of white space deeper than AddMainActionButtons. Thats because the first one is one level of abstraction lower, that second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the space out of the buttons by removing the border.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) for details.

[image]

Seen above is the single image split into 9 parts.  The N/S/E/W are buttons (East is activated - shown with a red border) and the rest are labels - each containing the relevant part of the original image.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7360696/418556) for a version that uses simpler images with `JToggleButton` instances.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the background to a transparent color?
This will remove the funky grey border around your image that often looks bad.

Comment: That will not only have no effect on the BG in some PLAFs, but is also a separate matter to the button border.  Would have been a poor comment, but is a horrid answer.

Comment: ok man. This works in Android to remove the grey backgound of an ImageButton so I was suggesting it. Just trying to help the guy.

Comment: Cool.  You're always free to delete answers.