# MouseListener on Sprites

Tags: java, animation, repaint, grid-layout, mouselistener

I am creating a 6x6 grid memory game. Its requirements is to use an image in a panel as a replacement for the buttons.

[image] 210 x 70

The project requires to implement MouseListeners on the following conditions:
The button will show first pokebell.
When the mouse hovers over the pokeball, it changes into the second pokeball.
When the mouse moves away from the pokeball, it reverts back to the first pokeball.
When the mouse clicks the pokeball, it changes to the 3rd pokeball.

Grid MouseEvents

```
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    for(i = 0; i < 36; i++){        
        if(e.getSource() == pkm[i]){                
                pkb[i].repaint();                       
        }
    }
}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {   
    for(i = 0; i < 36; i++){
        if(e.getSource() == pkm[i]){
                pkb[i].repaint();           
        }
    }  
}
```

PokeBall class

```
int start = 0;
int ht = 0, wt = 0;
URL url;
BufferedImage img, sp1;

public PokeBall(String imgLink, int w, int h, int x){
wt = w;
ht = h;
start = x;
url = this.getClass().getResource(imgLink);     
    try{   
        img = ImageIO.read(url);
    }
    catch(Exception e){         
    }
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    sp1 = img.getSubimage(start, 0, wt, ht);  
    g2d.drawImage(sp1,20,10,null);

    if(start == 70) {
        start = 0;
    } 
    else {
        start += 70;
    }           
}
```

My thought was that the change of sprite will be invoked on the corresponding mouse event, but instead I got the whole pokeball to animate in an infinite loop even when the mouse didn't invoke any event.

I need some ideas or suggestions on how to stop it from looping by itself and to actually call the designated pokeball.

Comment: *"The project **requires** to implement **MouseListeners** on the following conditions:"*  Wow! Tough requirement, given a `JToggleButton` could give that ability in just 3 lines of code.  See this [demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7360696/418556) for an example.

Comment: Yes. Sadly that's the requirement of our professor to use a panel instead of JButton or JToggleButton.

Comment: BTW - how do the following two things come into it?  [tag:animation] & [tag:gridlayout]

Comment: Also, is custom painting compulsory, or might you use a `JLabel` to display the appropriate image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the responsibility for painting the balls is the `PokeBall` class, it needs to know when the state has changed, so it makes sense to apply an `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` to it.  Then you don't need to care about trying to update grid locations and other fun stuff.

On your `GridPane`, I would then attach another `MouseListener` so you can detect when a ball is clicked and take appropriate action there...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MyPokeBalls {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyPokeBalls();
    }

    public MyPokeBalls() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new PokeBall());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class PokeBall extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage balls;
        private int ballWidth = 70;
        private int ballHeight = 70;
        private int ballOffset = 0;

        public PokeBall() {
            try {
                balls = ImageIO.read(new File("PokeBalls.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                private boolean isIn = false;

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    ballOffset = 1;
                    isIn = true;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    ballOffset = 0;
                    isIn = true;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    ballOffset = 2;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (isIn) {
                        ballOffset = 1;
                    } else {
                        ballOffset = 2;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }

            };

            addMouseListener(ma);
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(ballWidth, ballHeight);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (balls != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                BufferedImage ball = balls.getSubimage(ballWidth * ballOffset, 0, ballWidth, ballHeight);
                int x = (getWidth() - ball.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - ball.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(ball, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AbstractButton b=new JToggleButton(firstIcon);
b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
b.setFocusable(false);
b.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
b.setRolloverEnabled(true);
b.setRolloverIcon(secondIcon);
b.setSelectedIcon(thirdIcon);
```

Why reinventing the wheel?

Creating a grid of such buttons is quite simple…

Comment: Ok the comments on the question came while I wrote this…