# JButton in actionperformed

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jbutton

```
if("switch".equals(action))
{
    changeLunar();
    count++;
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        lunarButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("assets/sun.png"));
    }
    else
    {
        lunarButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("assets/moon.png"));
    }
}
```

So I am trying to make it where when you click a button, the button changes to another image, and when you click it again it goes back to the first image. But when I compile it says:

```
lunarButton can't be resolved to a variable
```

What am I to do?

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses. It sounds like you defined the original `lunarButton` as a local variable, but I'm just guessing

Comment: agree with @MadProgrammer...and you may need to declare a type for lunarButton (`JButton lunarButton = ...`)

Comment: @sfletche "assuming" that a `lunarButton` already exists, for something to be pressed, the OP should be able to use `JButton#setIcon` to change the icons...but I'm still only guessing :P

Comment: About "in actionPerformed", is this code fragment the "actionPerformed"?

Comment: yes blue it is. an di have the JButton lunarButton declared in init()

Comment: @user3427042 then, *assuming* you already have a `lunarButton`, why do you create a new button instead of changing the icon of the existing button?

Comment: Use a `JToggleButton` and set the default and selected icons for it.  Job done.  BTW - By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: `JToggleBtton` .. E.G. as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7359906/418556) (which is an MCVE, as you were advised to post by @MadProgrammer over 30 minutes ago).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I like the idea of the `JToggleButton`, but more context would be wonderful

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, the suggestion '`JToggleButton`' hardly speaks to the source of the compiler error.  I decided to vote to close for lack of a reproducible example.

Comment: @user3427042 Please share the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Error Message: Cannot Find Symbol**

> When a Java program is being compiled the compiler creates a list of all the identifiers in use. If it can't find what an identifier refers to (e.g., there is no declaration statement for a variable) it cannot complete the compilation. This is what the cannot find symbol error message is saying, it doesn't have enough information to piece together what the Java code wants to execute.

Please validate the variable `lunarButton` declared in your code and it **must be accessible** as well.

May be you have created it in `changeLunar()` method as local variable that can't be accessed outside the method instead use **instance variable** or just **return the value** from the `changeLunar()` method.

Instead of creating a new `JButton` every time you can simply change its icon using `JButton#setIcon()` method.